# Is there any spam filter for WFFM? Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160519)

Tags: wffm

We currently use WFFM for a contact us form on our site and are looking for some type of spam filter for the form.  We are running the latest reCaptcha but people still fill out our forms with spam on a daily basis.

Something with the ability to block messages with key words would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing ootb, but you could write your own. One option would be to create a custom save action (documentation -amongst lots of other blogs- here: https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/81/working_with_actions_and_validations/save_actions/create_a_new_save_action)

In that save action you could check on fields whether they contain any words you want to block and generate an error if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  We will have to add this in future development.